# Try to call a function within itself

Tags: python, function, recursion

I am new to the python. Recently, I follow the online python course to learn the python. Here is a simple question from the course:

Write a function called **item_order** that takes as input a string named **order**. The string contains only words for the items the customer can order separated by one space. The function returns a string that counts the number of each item and consolidates them in the following order:

> salad:[# salad] hamburger:[# hambruger] water:[# water].

The result example is: if `order = "salad water hamburger salad hamburger"` then the function returns

> salad:2 hamburger:2 water:1

I finished the question myself without any problems. The code is:

```
def item_order (order):
    num_sa = 0
    num_wa = 0
    num_ha = 0

    new_order = order.split(' ')

    for item in new_order:
        if item == 'salad':
            num_sa += 1
        elif item == 'water':
            num_wa += 1
        elif item == 'hamburger':
            num_ha += 1

    group = 'salad:'+str(num_sa)+' '+'hamburger:'+str(num_ha)+' '+'water:'+str(num_wa)

    return group

print('Please enter the order.')
order = raw_input('')

group = item_order(order)
print(group)
```

But just curious if the input 'order' has some mistakes then how could I change my code for that situation. So I modify my code like:

```
def item_order (order):
    num_sa = 0
    num_wa = 0
    num_ha = 0
    flag = 0

    new_order = order.split(' ')

    for item in new_order:
        if item == 'salad':
            num_sa += 1
        elif item == 'water':
            num_wa += 1
        elif item == 'hamburger':
            num_ha += 1
        else:
            flag = 1
            break

    if flag == 1:
        print('There is something wrong on the order you insert, please re-enter.')
        fix_order = raw_input('')
        item_order(fix_order)

    group = 'salad:'+str(num_sa)+' '+'hamburger:'+str(num_ha)+' '+'water:'+str(num_wa)

    return group

print('Please enter the order.')
order = raw_input('')

group = item_order(order)
print(group)
```

But I find there is problem which I cannot tell where the code has bug.

Eg: if I put `"salad water hamburger salad hamburge"` as input 'order', it will let me to re-enter again because the 'hamburge' is wrong.

So after I re-enter the correct order `"salad water hamburger salad hamburger"`, it will give me the result:

> "salad:2 hamburger:1 water:1"

But the number of hamburger should be 2. I think there is a problem when I try to call the function `item_order()` within itself.

Could someone help me to find the bug?

Answer (score 1):

```
if flag == 1:
    print('There is something wrong on the order you insert, please re-enter.')
    fix_order = raw_input('')
    item_order(fix_order)
```

This `item_order` call has no effect. You're not using the return value.

Remember that calling a function doesn't just jump to the start of the function - after the function returns, execution continues where the call happened.

Which in your case is this line:

```
group = 'salad:'+str(num_sa)+' '+'hamburger:'+str(num_ha)+' '+'water:'+str(num_wa)
```

These are still the variables from the original invalid `order`.

---

The easiest way to fix this code is to change

```
    item_order(fix_order)
```

to

```
    return item_order(fix_order)
```

That way you're ignoring the broken input and the `num_*` counts accumulated so far; instead you're forwarding the result of the fixed order to your own caller.

Comment: Wow. I now understand my problem. Thank you very much. Also thank @mrwyatt for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that your function, item_order, is returning a string, but you are not capturing it anywhere.  So when you call item_order in the if statement, you need to have a variable to catch the string it is returning.  For example:

```
if flag == 1:
    print('There is something wrong on the order you insert, please re-enter.')
    fix_order = raw_input('')
    group = item_order(fix_order)
    return group

group = 'salad:'+str(num_sa)+' '+'hamburger:'+str(num_ha)+' '+'water:'+str(num_wa)

return group
```

This would fix your problem by returning the output of the item_order function on the fix_order input.